# String Sort using lambda

Tags: python, sorting

**Can someone please explain this code:**

````py
print(*sorted(input(), ```**```key=lambda c: (c.isdigit() - c.islower(), c in '02468', c))```**```, sep='')
````

**Task:**

You are given a string S. S contains alphanumeric characters only. Your task is to sort the string  in the following manner:

1. All sorted lowercase letters are ahead of uppercase letters.
2. All sorted uppercase letters are ahead of digits.
3. All sorted odd digits are ahead of sorted even digits.

**Example:**

input = Sorting1234

output = ginortS1324

Answer (score 0):

key=some_function say **how** to sort. For each letter will be generated tuple of 3 elements. Then this tuples compared with each other. Letter that produced a 'lesser' tuple is placed earlier. Tuples are compared element-wise: first element of one tuple with first element of another tuple, second with second, etc. until first not-equial pair.